# How do I show the order while print keys from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
account = {"USD": 10, "HKD": 1000}
for key in account.keys():
   print(key)
```

I would like the output to be like:

1. USD
2. HKD

In my full program, there are other account with different number of currencies, so I cannot fix 1./2. before keys.
I have tried enumerate(), but it can't be used while accessing keys from dictionary.

Comment: have a look at `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: the criteria for the order is not clear, does it depend on the value of the key?

Comment: I just want to show 1. for the first currency, 2. for second until all currencies are posted

Comment: you could use enumerate easily then, in conjunction with an `OrderedDict`, to specify the index

Comment: From python3.6 python's dictionaries save the order of insertion of the keys. Try this `for i,k in enumerate(account,1): print(f'{i}. {k}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index, key in enumerate(your_dict.keys()):
    print(index, key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want.

```
account = {"USD": 10, "HKD": 1000}

for n, key in enumerate(account, start=1):
   print(f'{n}. {key}')
```

[Example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=account%20%3D%20%7B%22USD%22%3A%2010,%20%22HKD%22%3A%201000%7D%0Afor%20n,%20key%20in%20enumerate%28account,%20start%3D1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20print%28f'%7Bn%7D.%20%7Bkey%7D'%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)